# Grouping of elements of set with first n Natural numbers, excluding one arbitrary element, to give us a Sum equal to S

Tags: python, numbers, partition

Array with elements sorted in descending order - l

```
ans=[]
for t in l:
if t<=S:
    S-=t
    ans.append(t)
if S==0:
    break
```

ans, Gives us list with selected elements.

Please tell me whether it is satisfiable by all big numbers or not?

Comment: Please put some more effort into writing your question. You want to be understood. It's not on others to guess what your actual problem is.

Comment: My question is, is this the right way to get group elements, to give us sum=S.

Comment: That's impossible to say, since you don't provide any information about `l`

Comment: I dont get your question. Its missing a lot of information. Are you guaranteed that the largest numbers somehow sum up to S? 
Say l=[3,3,3] and S=4, then no subset of numbers from the list (not group) can be summed up to 4. Also please fix the indentation in the for loop

Comment: Sorry to all for creating a mess. Since it is a set, no repetition is allowed. For example, N=10 and the arbitrary value, which is omitted, is 5. Therefore content of L will be : 10,9,8,7,6,4,3,2,1. Now i have to partition them in two equal halves, having equal sum. In order to do this, is my above mentioned code good enough? This is what i am asking, once again sorry and thank you.

Comment: In that case the answer is no. Your code doesn't divide a list into any two halves. 
Have you written tests or anything that demonstrates what result your code generates?

Answer (score 1):

**No it doesn't work for all cases:**

**For example**: *S = 17 and l = [10,5,4,3]*

**The answer and will be:**
*ans = [10,5]* and
*S = 2* (because it didn't get down to 0)

**But it could have been solved by:** ans [10,4,3]

Answer (score 0):

For n=8 and omitted element=2.
This won't return the right answer.