# Partition number from 1 to n

Tags: c++, numbers, partition

The challenge is

> You are given two integers x and N. Consider all integers between 1
>   and N inclusive, except x. We want to partition these integers into
>   two disjoint sets (each integer has to appear in exactly one set) such
>   that the sums of numbers in these sets are equal.Find one valid
>   partition or determine that it doesn't exist.

This was asked in a coding competition in codechef and I wrote a solution for it in **C++** but that's saying wrong answer.

**Here's my code**

```
`#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
main(){
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        int n,x;
        cin>>x>>n;
        long long int sum = (n*(n+1))/2;
        sum = sum - x;
        if( ( (sum%2)==1 ) || n==2){
            cout<<"impossible";
        }
        else{
            sum /= 2;
            stack<char> s;
            for(int i=n;i>=1;i--){
                if(i!=x){
                    if( (sum-i) >= 0){
                        s.push('0');
                        sum = sum - i;
                    }else
                        s.push('1');
                }else
                    s.push('2');
            }
            if(s.top()=='0'){
                while(!s.empty()){
                    cout<<s.top();
                    s.pop();
                }
            }else if(s.top()=='1'){
                while(!s.empty()){
                    if(s.top()=='1')
                        s.top() = '0';
                    else if(s.top()=='0')
                        s.top() = '1';
                    cout<<s.top();
                    s.pop();
                }
            }else{
                cout<<s.top();
                s.pop();
                if(s.top()=='0'){
                    while(!s.empty()){
                        cout<<s.top();
                        s.pop();
                    }
                }else{
                    while(!s.empty()){
                        if(s.top()=='1')
                            s.top() = '0';
                        else if(s.top()=='0')
                            s.top() = '1';
                        cout<<s.top();
                        s.pop();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}`
```

What I did here is that I first found the sum of all numbers from 1 to N then removed x from it, after this if the sum is odd then you can't divide the numbers in 2 disjoint sets so print "impossible", if its not odd then you half it in two(each set will sum up to this) and start a loop from N to 1 and start subtracting i from the sum as long as sum-i is >= 0.

For each subtraction you put it in a stack as '0' and '1' so as to distinguish between the two groups. And when i becomes equal to x you insert a '2'.

At the end you print the stack. Printing the stack here may look complex because at first when I tried to print it normally the result showed wrong answer so I assumed it has taken the group where i=1 is there as group '0' and other one as group '1'.

The answer is still not coming. Please anyone tell if I'm wrong anywhere, I'm not asking for a direct code or answer just wanted to know what am I doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grouping of elements of set with first n Natural numbers, excluding one arbitrary element, to give us a Sum equal to S](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48169568/grouping-of-elements-of-set-with-first-n-natural-numbers-excluding-one-arbitrar)

Comment: 1.  What does this `'0'`, `'1'` and `'2'` represent?  Would an enum be clearer?  2.  I don't think this algorithm works.  Do you have any simple worked examples?

Comment: This is called the [**Partition Problem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem). But your code needs you and your debugger.

Comment: @KhalilKhalaf This is a special case of the partition problem. In particular, this problem is easy (as in, not NP) and has a solution whenever the sum, `((n*(n+1))/2 - x)/2`, is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You algorithm does not work for all cases. Here is a counterexample.
Take `N = 8` and `x = 2`; the set to partition is `S = {1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}`, and the sum of each partition is 17.
A solution is `A = {1, 3, 5, 8}, B = {4, 6, 7}`.
And here is how your algorithm will try to work it out:

```
A = {}, B = {}, sum = 17
A = {8}, B = {} sum = 9
A = {8, 7}, B = {} sum = 2
A = {8, 7}, B = {6} sum = 2
...
A = {8, 7}, B = {6, 5, 4, 3} sum = 2
A = {8, 7, 1}, B = {6, 5, 4, 3} sum = 1
```

As you can see, because S does not contain 2, your algorithm does not come up with a solution where `sum = 0`. <strike>Simply add the condition `(sum-i) != x` for the algorithm to work.</strike> Apparently, that does not work either.

Here is a more complicated solution. First let's make a few observations.

Depending on `N % 4`, `x` must be either odd or even for a solution to exist. Indeed, if `N % 4 = 0` or `N % 4 = 3`, then `N*(N+1)/2` is even, odd otherwise. Moreover, `x` must have the same parity, because `N*(N+1)/2 - x` must be even.

Also, any set of 4 consecutive integers can be partitioned in two sets with equal sum: the first and last integer in one set and the two middle ones in the other.

Let's take `N = 4`. If `x = 2`, the solution is `A = {1, 3}, B = {4}`. If `x = 4`, the solution is `A = {1, 2}, B = {3}`.

Taking the previous example with `N = 8` and `x = 2`, we can remove `{5, 6, 7, 8}`, reducing the problem to the previous one with `N = 4` and `x = 2`. That gives `A = {5, 8, 1, 3}, B = {6, 7, 4}`.

We can define two base cases for `N % 4 = 0` such that any other case can be reduced to a base case by removing sequences of 4 consecutive integers, from `x-1` descending, and from `N` descending. The base cases are `S = {1, x+1, x+2}` and `S = {1, 2, 3}`.

Using the same process, we can define base cases for `N % 4 = 1`: base cases are `S = {}` and `S = {1, 2, x+1, x+2}`.

For `N % 4 = 2`, the process is slightly different: the sequences to remove are from `2` ascending, and from `N` descending. The base cases are `S = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}`, `S = {1, x-1, x+1, x+2, x+3}` and `S = {1, x-3, x-2, x-1, x+1}`. For example, with `N = 14` and `x = 7`, removing `{2, 3, 4, 5}` and `{11, 12, 13, 14}` leaves `S = {1, 6, 8, 9, 10}` which corresponds to the second base case.

For `N % 4 = 3`, the process is yet slightly different: the sequences to remove are from `1` ascending, and from `N` descending. The base cases are `S = {x-1, x+1, x+2, x+3, x+4, x+5}`, `S = {x-3, x-2, x-1, x+1, x+2, x+3}` and `S = {x-5, x-4, x-3, x-2, x-1, x+1}`.

Here is a quick summary.

For `N % 4 = 0`:
remove sequences from `x-1` descending and `N` descending until one of the following.
`S = {1, x+1, x+2}`; `A = {1, x+1}, B = {x+2}`.
`S = {1, 2, 3}`; `A = {1, 2}, B = {3}`.

For `N % 4 = 1`:
remove sequences from `x-1` descending and `N` descending until one of the following.
`S = {}`; `A = {}, B = {}`.
`S = {1, 2, x+1, x+2}`; `A = {1, x+2}, B = {2, x+1}`.

For `N % 4 = 2`:
remove sequences from `2` ascending and `N` descending until one of the following.
`S = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}`; `A = {2, 3, 5}, B = {4, 6}`.
`S = {1, x-1, x+1, x+2, x+3}`; `A = {1, x-1, x+3}, B = {x+1, x+2}`.
`S = {1, x-3, x-2, x-1, x+1}`; `A = {1, x-2, x-1}, B = {x-3, x+1}`.

For `N % 4 = 3`:
remove sequences from `1` ascending and `N` descending until one of the following.
`S = {x-1, x+1, x+2, x+3, x+4, x+5}`; `A = {x-1, x+3, x+5}, B = {x+1, x+2, x+4}`.
`S = {x-3, x-2, x-1, x+1, x+2, x+3}`; `A = {x-3, x+1, x+2}, B = {x-2, x-1, x+3}`.
`S = {x-5, x-4, x-3, x-2, x-1, x+1}`; `A = {x-5, x-3, x+1}, B = {x-4, x-2, x-1}`.

Comment: I tried it and it solved 1 more test case but wasn't enough to solve all of them. I'm not understanding what more possible test cases are there that should be taken care of

Comment: And can you explain me the logic of how you deduced your two sets for the example you've taken above. Thanks.

Comment: @Rilee I just solved the example manually. I assume you do not have access to the problematic test cases. I do have a more complicated solution that works for sure, although I was convinced that adding the condition would suffice. I will look into it and describe that other solution when I have time. Also, where do you test your code? Being able to test mine the same way would make it easier for me.

Comment: Codechef.. if you can provide me with some link to the complex idea(if possible ) then I can look into it.

Comment: There is no link to the more complicated solution since I came up with it. I edited to present it, hopefully clearly enough. Don't you have a direct link to the problem where I can test things out? I'm not going to search Codechef for it.

Comment: Yeah I have https://www.codechef.com/JAN18/problems/PRTITION. Here you go! and thanks for the explanation.